# How to run certain elements of your programme based on whether a dataframe or matrix exists in R

Tags: r

I have a programme where I would like to do something slightly different if a certain df has already been created but the below won't work. Any suggestions? Also, would it be different for a matrix?

```
if (exists(df)) {
# do somthing    
} else {
# do other thing     
}
```

Comment: Try, `is.data.frame()` and similar for matrix `is.matrix()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (you would need to put the variable name in `""` (it needs to be a character string) for `exists`, e.g. `"df"`):

```
df <- data.frame(a = 3)

if (exists("df")) {
  print("df exists")
} else {
  print("df does not exist")
}
```

See documentation for `exists`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `is.data.frame` to check if there is already a dataframe

```
if (is.data.frame(df)) {
# do somthing    
} else {
# do other thing     
}
```

You can use `is.matrix` with similar use.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (is.data.frame(df)) { 
# do stuff to df
} else {
# do other thing     
} 

if (is.matrix(mx)) { 
# do stuff to mx
} else {
# do other thing     
}
```

Comment: You should add some explication to your code to make a complete answer. Even correct, code only answers are not very legible. Here is how to write a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer